# Bluetooth AVRCP only device

Tags: bluetooth, remote-control

Is there a Bluetooth device I can use with my Android phone which has nothing more than previous, play/pause, and next track buttons?

There are many AVRCP Bluetooth devices, but they are all also A2DP sinks, which I do not want – I plug my phone's headphone output into my car's aux input.

Ideally, I'd like something I can mount to the steering wheel so I can change tracks without trying to find the button on my touchscreen.

Alternatively, could I buy a [small A2DP/AVRCP device like this](http://www.ankaka.com/music-stereo-bluetooth-headset-a2dp-avrcp-profiles_p46608.html?zenid=snkgec8nd3jnopp2d4l6rkoh65) and configure Android to not send audio, but still respond to the track controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[Sony LiveView](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/products/accessories/overview/liveview#view=overview)** may fit the bill.

Comment: +10 - I [ordered](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004E2V4NM/) one and it arrived today.  This is *exactly* what I was looking for.  The wristband [wraps perfectly around my steering wheel spoke](http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/8191/20110208222127400.jpg); I could not ask for a better mount spot.  You wouldn't happen to know how to adjust this thing's screen timeout?  It turns off after just a few seconds.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't actually have one but I've been eyeing it for a while for the same reasons you had. I'm glad to hear it worked for you. I think I'm going to order one soon.